# text emerging out of a css box when showing the publications that are saved in a mysql data base

Tags: html, css

I have a page where results of a query to mysql db are shown, everything works fine but if i need to write a long line without spaces it emerges out of the text box i have
I would like to get the text inside of the white box
screen shot:
[Image screen shot]
code:

```
.caja-comentario{
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:400px;
    min-height:10px;
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: What would you like to happen to the text that is going g out of the box? Put another way: what is the desired output?

Comment: I woud like to get it inside the white box

Comment: How? By increasing the width of the box? Whatever your answer, edit it into the question.

Comment: Im sorry if im not very specific, im new to this, i wanted to get the text inside without increasing the size of the box, what i needed was:word-wrap: break-word thank you anyway

Comment: No problem and happy programming! Be sure to accept Syncro's answer if it answered your question. (There should be a check mark to the left of his answer somewhere)

Comment: Yeah i accepted it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add these CSS properties to the element where you place the text:

```
word-wrap:break-word;
word-break:break-all;
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/4wtoek7m/1